# React js: multiple child comments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to ask you some question about React.js. Now I am doing some React.js excercise and it seems I made some mistakes. It should be save, remove and edit buttons, textarea. When you click on edit button, textarea appears. When you click on save button, all things are return to default conditions.

But the computer shows me an empty screen.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>

   <script src = "react-master/../js/react.js"></script>
   <script src = "react-master/../js/react-dom.js"></script>
   <script src = "js/browser.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id = "example"></div>

    <script type = "text/babel">
        var Comment = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {editing: false}
            },
            edit: function(){
                this.setState({editing: true});
            },
            remove: function(){
                console.log("Removing comments");
            },
            save: function(){
                var val = this.refs.newText.value;
                console.log (val);
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },
            renderNormal: function(){
                return(
                    <div className = "comment-container">
                        <div className = "comment-text">{this.props.children}</div>
                        <button onClick = {this.edit}>Edit</button>
                        <button onClick = {this.remove}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            renderForm: function(){
                return(
                    <div className = "comment-container">
                        <textarea ref ="newText" defaultValue = {this.props.children}></textarea>
                        <button onClick = {this.save}>Save</button>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            render: function(){
                if (this.state.editing){
                    return this.renderForm();
                }else{
                    return this.renderNormal();
                }
            }
        });

        var Board = React.createClass({
            getInitialScale: function(){
                return (
                    comments: ["Ira", "Nata", "Nina"]
                )
            }, 
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div className = "board">{
                        this.state.comments.map(function(text, i){
                            return (<Comment key = {i}>{text}</Comment>);
                        }) 
                    }
                    </div>                      
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("example"));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What do I do wrong? 
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use JSX inside plain js, without using a transformer, hence a blank screen (there will also be some errors in the console).

JSX is nothing but a fancy word for using html tags and structure inside javascript (ex: see your render function).

Earlier, there was a way to compile JSX in the browser itself, but that seems to be deprecated (https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html). You could use the other link provided there, for an online repl.

A better option would be to setup node and use create-react-app (details here : https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). This way, you'll be able to consume a vast variety of libraries and utilities.

PS: Whenever in doubt, check the chrome developer tools (right click on screen > inspect element).

Answer (score 0):

You had some typo error in your code. If you open chrome developer tool you will see it. I have corrected your code as below:

1) `getInitialScale` -> `getInitialState`

2) return value in `getInitialState` must be object

```
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {comments: ["Ira", "Nata", "Nina"]}
    },
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id = "example"></div>
    
    <script type = "text/babel">
        var Comment = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {editing: false}
            },
            edit: function(){
                this.setState({editing: true});
            },
            remove: function(){
                console.log("Removing comments");
            },
            save: function(){
                var val = this.refs.newText.value;
                console.log (val);
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },
            renderNormal: function(){
                return(
                        <div className = "comment-container">
                            <div className = "comment-text">{this.props.children}</div>
                            <button onClick = {this.edit}>Edit</button>
                            <button onClick = {this.remove}>Remove</button>
                        </div>
                );
            },
            renderForm: function(){
                return(
                        <div className = "comment-container">
                            <textarea ref ="newText" defaultValue = {this.props.children}></textarea>
                            <button onClick = {this.save}>Save</button>
                        </div>
                );
            },
            render: function(){
                if (this.state.editing){
                    return this.renderForm();
                }else{
                    return this.renderNormal();
                }
            }
        });
    
        var Board = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return{
                    comments: ["Ira", "Nata", "Nina"]
                }
            },
            render: function(){
                return (
                        <div className = "board">{
                            this.state.comments.map(function(text, i){
                                return (<Comment key = {i}>{text}</Comment>);
                            })
                        }
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });
    
        ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("example"));
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Besides, you should install [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) for chrome, it's very helpful to debug and check state( props) value.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to separate your code from the DOM. So you can create a file "abc.js" and copy this. I have converted your code into the React format and it is working now.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Comment extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        editing : false,
        textValue: this.props.textValue
      }
      this.edit = this.edit.bind(this)
      this.remove = this.remove.bind(this)
      this.save = this.save.bind(this)
    }
    edit(){
      this.setState({editing: true});
    }
    remove(){
      console.log("Removing comments");
    }
    save(){
        var val = this.refs.newText.value;
        console.log (val);
        this.setState({editing: false, textValue : val});
    }
    renderNormal(){
        return(
            <div className = "comment-container">
                <div className = "comment-text">{this.state.textValue}</div>
                <button onClick = {this.edit}>Edit</button>
                <button onClick = {this.remove}>Remove</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    renderForm(){
        return(
            <div>
                <textarea ref ="newText" ></textarea>
                <button onClick = {this.save}>Save</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    render(){
        if (this.state.editing){
            return this.renderForm();
        }else{
            return this.renderNormal();
        }
    }
  }

    class Board extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
          super(props)
          this.state = {
            comments : ["Ira", "Nata", "Nina"]
          }
        }

        render(){
            const myComp = this.state.comments.map((a) =>{
              return (
                <Comment textValue={a}/>
              )
            })
            return (
                    <div>
                    {myComp}
                    </div>
            )
        }
    }

        ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById('root'));
```